# When to load textures?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, mobile-phones, textures

I'm currently working on a couple of windows phone projects (Although the question may also fit iphone/android) and it got me thinking, when is the best time to load textures from the content manager.

At first, I was loading them all up, from my Game base class, and passing them along as required. Quickly getting sick of this, I have created a small resource manager class, which I pass out to anything that requires it.

So I'm thinking, that perhaps its best that I actually load the texture in, when a class requires it, and then assign it to a variable, so when I need it again - it will be all ready to go... is this the best way (efficient?, fastest?) to handle loading resources? If not, how would you recommend I go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't create any kind of "resource manager" class. Just pass the XNA `ContentManager` class around (the instance you get from `Game.Content`).

The default content manager will automatically handle reusing loaded objects for you. So you can `Content.Load<Texture2D>("something")` from multiple places and you will always get back the *same* texture instance.

So if you have a bunch of classes for your game objects, with the standard design of giving each an `Update` and a `Draw` method that you call from the respective methods in `Game` -  just add another method: `LoadContent` to those classes, that accepts an argument of `ContentManager`.

You can call that method from your game's `LoadContent` method.

If, later, you want to implement some kind of system of delay-loading things (for example: loading content when changing levels), you can also call your game classes' `LoadContent` method from your game's `Update` method (but keep in mind that loading content is slow - so you might want to throw up a "loading" screen).

Unloading content is slightly trickier. Anything you create yourself you must unload. But anything loaded from a `ContentManager` (because the instances are shared) should only be unloaded by that content manager (`Game` will handle unloading its `Content` member when it needs to). You may find [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx) worth reading.

Comment: Would passing the contentManager class around be better than calling GameState.Instance.LoadTexture2D("Texture") ?

Comment: Am I right in thinking GameState is a singleton? It's not *terrible*, but I've found that passing a ContentManager around is more flexible in the long term. Also I wouldn't even bother with the singleton - if you want to go that route - just make it `public static` and manage initialising it in your Game class. (This is my game development answer - the proper software engineering answer is simply: "Yes!")